# What is the proper way to make an element fill the remaining vertical space in its container

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a set height which will hold arbitrary elements and another div that I wish to fill the remaining space, so that the div is filled.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTmVk/)

html:

```
<div class=container>
    <div class=title>
        <h1> title </h1>
    </div>
    <div class=body>
        <h1> stuff here </h1>    
    </div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
.container {
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: 300px;
}
.title {
    background: blue;    
}
.body {
    background: green;
}
```

I want the green div to fill the white space within the red border so that it looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/keDNY/1/) but without setting the height explicitly, because the sizes of the title and containing divs are dynamic.

Comment: Easy? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/wTmVk/7/

Comment: The backgrounds were just used as an example. The body element actually contains a multi select that I want to fill the height.

Comment: Riiiight. I don't know a way without modifying the markup's layout, since you want to preserve flow. There isn't a way with pure CSS to say "take x to have so much, and y to have what's left". Not that I've come across yet.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Ok thanks, Can javascript get and set the position of the corners or edges of elements?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by corners or edges, but if you mean backfill a height based on another element's height being subtracted from the common parent, yes, Javascript can do that. jQuery makes it a lot easier, mind you, but for one little thing, may be overkill. Getting actual element height across browsers, though, can be challenging.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it would be to put the title *inside* the body. Then you can set the body height to 100% (since its container has a fixed height) and the title will only fill what it needs, with its own background. By combining related elements into one container, it can be much simpler to move stuff around in your layout, too.

html:

```
<div class=container>
    <div class=body>
        <div class=title>
            <h1> title </h1>
        </div>
    <h1> stuff here </h1>    
    </div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
.container {
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: 300px;
}
.title {
    background: blue;

}
.body {
    height:100%;
    background: green;
}
```

You can always add another element inside the container to contain your multi-select, and have it inherit the properties of the parent container.

Comment: Ultimately it is the multi select that I want to fill all of the area that is green in my example, which properties should be inherited for this to work?

Comment: You should inherit color or anything else you want to inherit. I would recommend using a flexible height for the container, though, because some browsers (particularly mobile browsers which use variable font sizes) will display text bigger than others, and you don't want an awkward overflow to make your page look messy.